# flask кеширует страницу

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Всем доброго времени суток.
Проблема в том что есть сервис который по запросу лезет в базу - достает инфу - формирует датафреймы и потом выгружает все в эксель формате.

```
def get_status_info():
    """
    :return: {'status1' : count, ...}
    """
    result = dict()
    sql = text(query_for_statuses)
    query = db.engine.execute(sql)

    for row in query.fetchall():
        result[row[0]] = row[1]

    return result


def get_cnt_expected_doc():
    """
    :return: int
    """
    sql = text(count_expected_doc)
    query = db.engine.execute(sql)
    res = query.fetchone()[0]

    return res
```

Все хорошо работает но именно по этому запросу сервис отдает актуальную информацию только первый раз, потом при след запросу берет от куда то из кеша файл и кидает его повторно (данные не подтягиваются снова из базы), более того в логе даже не видно что запрос пришел. При этом никакие настройки для кеширования я не выставлял и остальные запросы отрабатывают каждый раз при обращении.

```
@reports_api.route('/reports/queue_statuses', methods=['GET'])
def queue_statuses():
    file = report_queue_statuses()

    return send_from_directory(BaseConfig.LOAD_FOLDER, file, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel', as_attachment=True)
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: То есть страница не отправляет новые данные, да?

Comment: А на чём сервис то стоит? Может там где-то на переднем крае Nginx какой-нибудь страницы кэширует или ещё кто )  А ещё может быть, что браузер вообще не запрашивает страницу (если обращаетесь браузером). Я бы сначала проверил через Fiddler идёт ли вообще запрос на сервер.

Comment: @Mattern да, страница отдает старый результат (при этом само запрос на сервер не приходит (в логах смотрю))

Comment: @CrazyElf стоит на nginx ничего там не кешируется) настройки вообще минимальные, только таймауты выставлены. сейчас curl'ом отправил - действительно, так запрос передается, а с браузера (обновил кеш) и снова первый запрос прошел, последующие - выдает данные первого запроса. И это только на конкретном url'е , очень странно

Comment: @alexjust Ну, я не очень силён в данном вопросе, но метода борьбы знаю как минимум два. Первый вариант - сервер должен выдавать заголовок, в котором будет написано, что страница устаревает через какое-то время (не знаю, за какое время у вас информация обновляется). Второй вариант - генерировать при запросе каждый раз некий допольнительный уникальный id в запрашиваемом URL-е, тогда браузер не будет кэшировать запрос - он ведь разный. Вообще, тема старая, погуглите, должны быть ещё рецепты.

Comment: @alexjust Вообще, если у вас содержимое меняется, хотя URL один и тот же, то именно вы как-то должны позаботиться, чтобы браузер об этом узнал. Он вполне вправе думать, что если URL тот же, то и информация там не менялась, нечего её лишний раз запрашивать у сервера.

Comment: @CrazyElf да спасибо, добавил настройки кэша в header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response = send_from_directory(BaseConfig.LOAD_FOLDER, file, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel',
                                   as_attachment=True)
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
return response
```

исправил настройку кэша ответа и проблема решилась.